# Pandas dataframe conditional cumulative sum based on date range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
         Date            Party    Status
-------------------------------------------
0        01-01-2018      John     Sent
1        13-01-2018      Lisa     Received
2        15-01-2018      Will     Received
3        19-01-2018      Mark     Sent
4        02-02-2018      Will     Sent
5        28-02-2018      John     Received
```

I would like to add new columns that perform a `.cumsum()`, but it is conditional on the dates. It would look like this:

```
                                                Num of Sent         Num of Received
         Date            Party    Status        in Past 30 Days     in Past 30 Days
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0        01-01-2018      John     Sent          1                   0
1        13-01-2018      Lisa     Received      1                   1
2        15-01-2018      Will     Received      1                   2
3        19-01-2018      Mark     Sent          2                   2
4        02-02-2018      Will     Sent          2                   2
5        28-02-2018      John     Received      1                   1
```

I managed to implement what I need by writing the following code:

```
def inner_func(date_var, status_var, date_array, status_array):
    sent_increment = 0
    received_increment = 0

    for k in range(0, len(date_array)):
        if((date_var - date_array[k]).days <= 30):
            if(status_array[k] == "Sent"):
                sent_increment += 1
            elif(status_array[k] == "Received"):
                received_increment += 1

    return sent_increment, received_increment
```

```
import pandas as pd
import time
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.to_datetime(["01-01-2018", "13-01-2018", "15-01-2018", "19-01-2018", "02-02-2018", "28-02-2018"]),
                   "Party": ["John", "Lisa", "Will", "Mark", "Will", "John"],
                   "Status": ["Sent", "Received", "Received", "Sent", "Sent", "Received"]})

df = df.sort_values("Date")
date_array = []
status_array = []

for i in range(0, len(df)):
        date_var = df.loc[i,"Date"]
        date_array.append(date_var)
        status_var = df.loc[i,"Status"]
        status_array.append(status_var)
        sent_count, received_count = inner_func(date_var, status_var, date_array, status_array)
        df.loc[i, "Num of Sent in Past 30 days"] = sent_count
        df.loc[i, "Num of Received in Past 30 days"] = received_count
```

However, the process is computationally expensive and painfully slow when `df` is large, since the nested loops go through the dataframe twice. Is there a more pythonic way to implement what I am trying to achieve without iterating through the dataframe in the way I am doing?

**Update 2**

Michael has provided the solution to what I am looking for: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64293354/10199500). Lets assume that I want to apply the solution on `groupby` objects. For example, using the rolling solution to compute the cumulative sums based for each party:

```
                                                Sent past 30       Received past 30
         Date            Party    Status        days by party      days by party
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0        01-01-2018      John     Sent          1                   0
1        13-01-2018      Lisa     Received      0                   1
2        15-01-2018      Will     Received      0                   1
3        19-01-2018      Mark     Sent          1                   0
4        02-02-2018      Will     Sent          1                   1
5        28-02-2018      John     Received      0                   1
```

I have attempted to regenerate the solution for the using the `groupby` method below:

```
l = []
grp_obj = df.groupby("Party")
grp_obj.rolling('30D',  min_periods=1)["dummy"].apply(lambda x: l.append(x.value_counts()) or 0)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

But I ended up with incorrect values. I know that it is happening because the `concat` method is combining the dataframes without condsidering their indices, since `groupby` orders the data differently. Is there a way I can modify the list appending to include the original index, such that I can merge/join the value_counts dataframe to the original one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set `Date` as index and convert `Status` temporary to a categorical you can use [`pd.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with a little trick

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
df['dummy'] = df['Status'].astype('category',copy=False).cat.codes
l = []
df.rolling('30D', min_periods=1)['dummy'].apply(lambda x: l.append(x.value_counts()) or 0)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
pd.concat(
    [df,
    (pd.DataFrame(l)
        .rename(columns={1.0: "Sent past 30 Days", 0.0: "Received past 30 Days"})
        .fillna(0)
        .astype('int'))
    ], axis=1).drop('dummy', 1)
```

Out:

```
        Date Party    Status  Received past 30 Days  Sent past 30 Days
0 2018-01-01  John      Sent                      0                  1
1 2018-01-13  Lisa  Received                      1                  1
2 2018-01-15  Will  Received                      2                  1
3 2018-01-19  Mark      Sent                      2                  2
4 2018-02-02  Will      Sent                      2                  2
5 2018-02-28  John  Received                      1                  1
```

---

### Maintaining an original index to allow subsequent merging

Slightly adjust the data to have different sequences in `Date` and `index`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.to_datetime(["01-01-2018", "13-01-2018", "03-01-2018", "19-01-2018", "08-02-2018", "22-02-2018"]),
                   "Party": ["John", "Lisa", "Will", "Mark", "Will", "John"],
                   "Status": ["Sent", "Received", "Received", "Sent", "Sent", "Received"]})
df
```

Out:

```
        Date Party    Status
0 2018-01-01  John      Sent
1 2018-01-13  Lisa  Received
2 2018-03-01  Will  Received
3 2018-01-19  Mark      Sent
4 2018-08-02  Will      Sent
5 2018-02-22  John  Received
```

Store the original index after sorting by `Date` and reindex after operationing on the dataframe sorted by `Date`

```
df = df.sort_values('Date')
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.set_index('Date')
df['dummy'] = df['Status'].astype('category',copy=False).cat.codes
l = []
df.rolling('30D', min_periods=1)['dummy'].apply(lambda x: l.append(x.value_counts()) or 0)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = pd.concat(
      [df,
      (pd.DataFrame(l)
          .rename(columns={1.0: "Sent past 30 Days", 0.0: "Received past 30 Days"})
          .fillna(0)
          .astype('int'))
      ], axis=1).drop('dummy', 1)
df.set_index('index')
```

Out:

```
            Date Party    Status  Received past 30 Days  Sent past 30 Days
index                                                                     
0     2018-01-01  John      Sent                      0                  1
1     2018-01-13  Lisa  Received                      1                  1
3     2018-01-19  Mark      Sent                      1                  2
5     2018-02-22  John  Received                      1                  0
2     2018-03-01  Will  Received                      2                  0
4     2018-08-02  Will      Sent                      0                  1
```

---

### Counting values in groups

Sort by `Party` and `Date` first to get the right order to append the grouped counts

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.to_datetime(["01-01-2018", "13-01-2018", "15-01-2018", "19-01-2018", "02-02-2018", "28-02-2018"]),
                   "Party": ["John", "Lisa", "Will", "Mark", "Will", "John"],
                   "Status": ["Sent", "Received", "Received", "Sent", "Sent", "Received"]})
df = df.sort_values(['Party','Date'])
```

After that reindex before `concat` to append to the right rows

```
df = df.set_index('Date')
df['dummy'] = df['Status'].astype('category',copy=False).cat.codes
l = []
df.groupby('Party').rolling('30D', min_periods=1)['dummy'].apply(lambda x: l.append(x.value_counts()) or 0)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

pd.concat(
      [df,
      (pd.DataFrame(l)
          .rename(columns={1.0: "Sent past 30 Days", 0.0: "Received past 30 Days"})
          .fillna(0)
          .astype('int'))
      ], axis=1).drop('dummy', 1).sort_values('Date')
```

Out:

```
        Date Party    Status  Received past 30 Days  Sent past 30 Days
0 2018-01-01  John      Sent                      0                  1
2 2018-01-13  Lisa  Received                      1                  0
4 2018-01-15  Will  Received                      1                  0
3 2018-01-19  Mark      Sent                      0                  1
5 2018-02-02  Will      Sent                      1                  1
1 2018-02-28  John  Received                      1                  0
```

### Micro-Benchmark

As this solution is also iterating over the dataset I compared the running times of both approaches. Only very small datasets were used because the original solution's runtime was increasing fast.

Results

[image: benchmark results]

Code to reproduce the benchmark

```py
import pandas as pd
import perfplot

def makedata(n=1):
  df = pd.DataFrame({"Date": pd.to_datetime(["01-01-2018", "13-01-2018", "15-01-2018", "19-01-2018", "02-02-2018", "28-02-2018"]*n),
                   "Party": ["John", "Lisa", "Will", "Mark", "Will", "John"]*n,
                   "Status": ["Sent", "Received", "Received", "Sent", "Sent", "Received"]*n})

  return df.sort_values("Date")

def rolling(df):
  df = df.set_index('Date')
  df['dummy'] = df['Status'].astype('category',copy=False).cat.codes
  l = []
  df.rolling('30D', min_periods=1)['dummy'].apply(lambda x: l.append(x.value_counts()) or 0)
  df.reset_index(inplace=True)
  return pd.concat(
      [df,
      (pd.DataFrame(l)
          .rename(columns={1.0: "Sent past 30 Days", 0.0: "Received past 30 Days"})
          .fillna(0)
          .astype('int'))
      ], axis=1).drop('dummy', 1)

def forloop(df):
  date_array = []
  status_array = []
  def inner_func(date_var, status_var, date_array, status_array):
      sent_increment = 0
      received_increment = 0

      for k in range(0, len(date_array)):
          if((date_var - date_array[k]).days <= 30):
              if(status_array[k] == "Sent"):
                  sent_increment += 1
              elif(status_array[k] == "Received"):
                  received_increment += 1

      return sent_increment, received_increment

  for i in range(0, len(df)):
          date_var = df.loc[i,"Date"]
          date_array.append(date_var)
          status_var = df.loc[i,"Status"]
          status_array.append(status_var)
          sent_count, received_count = inner_func(date_var, status_var, date_array, status_array)
          df.loc[i, "Num of Sent in Past 30 days"] = sent_count
          df.loc[i, "Num of Received in Past 30 days"] = received_count
  return df

perfplot.show(
    setup=makedata,
    kernels=[forloop, rolling],
    n_range=[x for x in range(5, 105, 5)],
    equality_check=None,
    xlabel='len(df)'
)
```

Comment: That's a really good answer. Is there a way to append items into the "l" list based on the original index instead of the date order, or appending the original indices to a separate list? I am applying the `rolling` to the `groupby` method, in order to get the new parameters based on the parties history, so I am trying to maintain the original index for `join` or `merge` methods.

Comment: I think a simple way to maintain an original index would be to store the original index and reindex after the operations. I added an example for that requirement.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't rephrase it correctly. Maintaining the index itself is quite simple, but maintaining the indices for groupedby objects isn't. I updated my question to include the problem extension I attempted to implement.

Comment: Added this requirement, too. Please consider to ask for additional requirements in another question. This answer is getting quite confusing and hard to follow for other readers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not sure how it did not cross my mind to sort by two columns.